# Is one loop better than several of them?

Tags: c++, performance

I've been working on my implementation of BigInteger, and when I was contemplating the solution for addition, I decided to go with cleaner one, which had in mind adding corresponding digits in function and "normalizing" them later. Like in the following example

> 999 999 + 111 111
>   = 10 10 10 10 10 10 (value after addition)
>   = 1 111 110 (value after normalization)

But since then I was wondering about how it affects the efficiency of the program. Are several loops doing small things each generally going to work faster than one big nested loop?
For example, using

```
int a[7]={0,9,9,9,9,9,9};
int b[7]={0,1,1,1,1,1,1};
int c[7];
```

Is this,

```
for(int q=0; q<7; ++q){
    c[q]=a[q]+b[q];
    if(c[q]>9){
        c[q-1]=c[q]/10;
        c[q]%=10;
    }
}
```

better than this

```
for(int q=0; q<7; ++q){
    c[q]=a[q]+b[q];
}
for(int q=0;q<7;++q){
    if(c[q]>9){
        c[q-1]=c[q]/10;
        c[q]%=10;
    }
}
```

And what about bigger loops, that have much more things to go through on each iteration?

**UPD.**
As someone suggested I did measure performance time for both examples. For two loops the average time (for 100mil. elements) ~4.85sec. For one loop ~3.72sec

Comment: Normalise as you go, it will be better for cache coherency as you only have to visit each element once.  Just include a carry (initialised to 0) in your sum for each cell.  That said, questions regarding performance should always say _"try both/all and profile"_

Comment: Look at the assembly language generated by the compiler.  Next, **profile**.

Comment: [Race Your Horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Abracadabra!... Woops. My Black Magic box doesn't know the answer. **Quips aside:** Have you measured? What assembly did your compiler produce? Optimizations enabled? We can't tell you which is "faster" without some empirical measurements and numbers.

Comment: My analytical abilities of assembly consist of merely looking at length of the produced file. File with two loops is 20 lines longer :/

Comment: @Mike Mike: If performance is a significant goal here then consider reducing the number of iterations by using a larger base than 10. A larger power of ten will work if decimal conversion is frequent though naturally binary tends to speed things up.

Comment: @doynax it really isn't. I was just wondering about how different implementations perform

Comment: sorry for the offtopic, but that algorithm does not compute the sum (just in case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to tell which one of the two approaches will be more efficient. It probably varies among C++ compiler vendors and within a single vendor, from version to version of their compiler.

The bottom line is:

1. You will never know unless you benchmark.
2. As usual, it is almost certain that it does not matter anyway, and you are most probably unduly concerned about performance, like the vast majority of programmers do, in the vast majority of cases.
3. At the end of the day, all that matters is what is more readable and more maintainable.  Code maintainability is ***far*** more important than saving clock cycles.
4. If you decide to follow the wise path of "what is more readable" keep in mind that different folks find different things more readable.  For example, I personally hate surprises when I am reading code, so I would be rather annoyed to read your first loop which allows decimal digits to receive erroneous values outside of the 0-9 range, only to find out later that you are finally remedying that with another loop.